# How to set a formula for a entire column?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to apply a simple formula into a entire column, this is to prevent having to keep pasting the formula into said column when i add a row...

```
=IFERROR(D1-C1)
```

is the formula that i want to fill the entire column G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(D:D-C:C, "error"))
```

Comment: Thanks, was using correct formula just not in the correct way. Thanks a lot xD.